# Encode Arbitrary Characters to json array from php and use them in Android

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I am trying to populate a `listView` from database using JSON. The `listView` populates fine but the characters are replaced with question marks. I looked at the JSON. The characters are in Greek.

[My JSON Output](http://reservations.cretantaxiservices.gr/files/getcategories.php)

My php code:

```
    <?php
    try {
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', 'password');
        $handler->query( 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8' );
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
    $query = $handler->query( 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8' );
    $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM markoglou_order');
    $records = array();
    $records = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json['categories_markoglou'] = $records;
    echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    ?>
```

Screenshot:

[image: asd]

**EDIT:**

I already tried using `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do the Following:**

1. Change your database Collation to utf8_general_ci and also use the same collation on the tables that you need
2. Use the same collation on the fields of the tables only(varchar, text)
3. Modify your file like the following:

   ```
   <?php 
   mb_http_output("utf-8");
   header("Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
   try {

   $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', 'password');


   $handler->query( 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8' );
   $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      die();
   }

   $query = $handler->query( 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8' );
   $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM markoglou_order');
   $records = array();

   $records = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $json['categories_markoglou'] = $records;
   echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

   ?>
   ```

And then you are going to have the desired output in Greek language.

Hope it helps!!!